# Evaluate $ \int \frac{dx}{\sin{x}+\cos{x}}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$$ I=\int \frac{dx}{\sin{x}+\cos{x}}$$
My approach:
$$\sin{x}+\cos{x}=\sqrt 2 \left({\sin{x}\over \sqrt 2}+{\cos{x}\over \sqrt 2}\right) =\sqrt 2 \left({\sin{x}\cos{{\pi\over 4}}}+\cos{x}\sin{\pi\over 4}\right)=\sqrt 2 \sin \left({x+{\pi\over 4}} \right) $$

$$ \Rightarrow I=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt 2 \sin \left({x+{\pi\over 4}} \right)}$$
$$= {1\over \sqrt2} \int {\csc \left({x+{\pi\over 4}} \right)}dx$$
$$={1\over \sqrt2}\log|\csc{\left({x+{\pi\over 4}} \right)}-\cot{\left({x+{\pi\over 4}} \right)}|+C  $$

Any better way to do this?

Comment: Better in what way? Easier? Faster? More intuitive? Deeper?

Comment: This method was used by my teacher in the class, unless or otherwise I wouldn't have been able solve this, so perhaps a more intuitive way?

Comment: $u = \tan {x \over 2}$ works well here

Comment: Well, $\int\frac{1}{\sin t}\,dt=\log\left|\tan\frac{t}{2}\right|+c$, but, apart from this, I see nothing much simpler.

Comment: @windircurse True, but I wouldn't call that more intuitve :/

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen perhaps not more intuitive, but it's often learned as a method, so if they mentioned it in class, it's definitely easier
if not, however, then yeah, it's even more unintuitive

Comment: If this was a definite integral over some reasonable period then there would be a nice visual... but the antiderivative? hmm..

Comment: @windicurse $u=\tan\frac{x}{2} \Rightarrow x=2\tan^{-1}u.$ What then? I've haven't learnt about this method

Comment: @mikealise https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula check this link on how to express $\sin$ and $\cos$ using tangent half-angle, you'd get an expression on which you would have to use partial fraction decomposition

but, as Brevan already mentioned, if you haven't learned it yet, it does look even more unintuitive

Comment: @windicurse Is this what you mean? http://imgur.com/a/RyJNo   I expressed $\sin x$ & $\cos x$ in terms of $ \tan {x\over 2} $  and solved it.